# 30 days of code hackerrank day1

Tags: java

I was solving this hackerrank 30 days of code challenge. The code is below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class jabcexample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        String s = "HackerRank ";

        /* Declare second integer, double, and String variables. */
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            /* Declare second integer, double, and String variables. */
            int i2;
            double d2;
            String s2;

            /* Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.*/
            i2 = scan.nextInt();
            d2 = scan.nextDouble();

            scan.nextLine(); // This line
            s2 = scan.nextLine();

            /* Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line. */
            System.out.println(i + i2);

            /* Print the sum of the double variables on a new line. */
            System.out.println(d + d2);

            /* Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line;
            the 's' variable above should be printed first. */
            System.out.println(s.concat(s2));
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I added an extra line `scan.nextLine();` because without it the compiler doesn't even notice the next line that is `s2 = scan.nextLine();`. Why compiler doesn't notice `s2=scan.nextLine();` without writing `scan.nextLine();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the compiler and everything with how Scanner behaves.

If you read the Java docs you will see Sanner.nextLine() does

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.

Now you may be wondering what is left after you called

```
i2 = scan.nextInt();
d2 = scan.nextDouble();
```

In this case it is the carriage return characters. Calling `scan.nextLine()` reads those character and sets the position to the beginning of the next line.

Comment: Thanks. I was also missing the Carriage return characters concept.